# Исключение при добавлении объектов в ListView

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться, в чём ошибка, почему NullPointer.
Задача: отправляю запрос POST, приходит ответ в виде массива. Нужно его занести в ListView (кастомный).
XML:
listmsg.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ed_but">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="button_click"
        android:text="send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Элементы Listview: list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is text1"
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dddd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/author"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author"
            android:text="--> "
            android:textSize="12dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dddd"
            android:text="This is "
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="10.12.2011,16:40"
            android:textSize="8dip" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Главное активити:

```
public class ListviewActivity extends Activity 
{

    protected static final LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
       private String AUTHORKEY;
       private String TEXTKEY;
    private String TIMEKEY;
       private String[] names = {AUTHORKEY, TEXTKEY, TIMEKEY};
       int[] to_id = {R.id.author, R.id.text, R.id.time};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)        
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listmsg);        
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, R.layout.list, names, to_id);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    }
 }
```

Адаптер:

```
 public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
        private final Activity context;
        private String[] name;
        private int[] tolayout;
         static ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data;

        public MySimpleAdapter(Activity context, int resource, String[] n, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, n, to);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.name = n;

            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> hm;
            String s = (String) POST.rebutmsg();
            String [] t = s.split("%");
             int i;

              for(i=0; i<=59;i++){

                  hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                                  hm.put(name[0], t[i]);
                                  i++;
                                  hm.put(name[1], t[i]);
                                  i++;
                                  hm.put(name[2], t[i]);
                                  data.add(hm);
                                 }

        }
      }
```

Вот ошибки:

```
02-14 19:27:04.353: W/dalvikvm(10707): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fkn.chat/com.fkn.chat.ListviewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:454)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at com.fkn.chat.ListviewActivity.onCreate(ListviewActivity.java:55)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-14 19:27:04.363: E/AndroidRuntime(10707):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: У вас в массиве `names` значения не равны null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, я с помощью debug увидел свою ошибку. Я ничего не заношу в AUTHORKEY, TEXTKEY, TIMEKEY. Ошибка по невнимательности. Спасибо за помощь.